# What modelling tools are available to design a robot

Tags: design

I am planning to build a robot.

1) What free or low cost robot modelling tools exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some that I know of:

Solidworks student edition: 
http://www.solidworks.com/sw/education/cad-faq-students.htm
(Free for students who use a school's privately assigned password, otherwise $149)

AutoCAD Student version: http://students.autodesk.com/ (Free for students)

Google Sketchup: http://www.sketchup.com/products/sketchup-make (Free)

FreeCAD: http://www.freecadweb.org/ (Free)

Comment: `Blender` is worth being added here (I'm adding as a comment since the thread is closed and I can't post a new answer).

Comment: I created a video where I show how to get the moving graphics of a mechanical arm
https://youtu.be/crJXUlzJ918